# VBscript Automate command line "Yes/No" q‌u‌e‌s‌t‌i‌o‌n

Tags: shell, command-line, vbscript, automation, shell-exec

I have a VBscript that stops a process and starts it.

There is a Yes/No question that pops up in the command line I need to answer "Yes"
how can I do that pragmatically?

So far I have:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wshShell
On Error Resume Next
   Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Wscript.Quit
   End If
   wshShell.Run  "cmd.exe /C cd C:\WINDOWS\system32 & process.exe STOP"
   WScript.Sleep 15000
   wshShell.Run  "cmd.exe /C cd C:\WINDOWS\system32 & process.exe START"
On Error Goto 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this example on the program that wants the input:

```
wshShell.Run  "cmd.exe /C cd C:\WINDOWS\system32 & ( echo Yes|process.exe STOP )"
```

The `echo Yes` command will include the `ENTER` key. i.e.: `Y` + `e` + `s` + `ENTER`